# Macro to send pivot table in body

Tags: excel, macros, pivot-table, vba

I have got a Pivot table and I would like to send it with one push of a button. I'm not an expert of macros but as there is an option to send a selected range `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E368").Select` I believe there should be a way to send a pivot table which has a specific name assigned to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below copies the "**SAsPerformance**" Pivot Table data range:

```
Dim PvtTbl                  As PivotTable

Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("SA's Performance").PivotTables("SAsPerformance")
PvtTbl.TableRange2.Copy
```

Comment: I got this code:
`Sub SendPivot()
   SAsPerformance.TableRange2.Copy
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Item.To = "mailing list"
      .Item.Subject = "Performance report"
      .Item.Send
   End With
MsgBox "Congratulations, e-mail has been sent"
End Sub`

But when I assign it to the the button it goes into the debugging screen and highlights `SAsPerformance.TableRange2.Copy`

Where could be the problem at?

Comment: @Martin did you declare and setup **SAsPerformance** `as a PivotTable` first ?

Comment: Here is the link to the [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7_yVmVXbyObbWI0dTNpWkFscGs/view?usp=sharing) for what I believe i have set the name up correctly.

Comment: @Martin almost, what is the Sheet name ? where you have your Pivot Table ?